# Azure DevOps: Chocolatey, Install Google Chrome Issue

Tags: azure, selenium, google-chrome, azure-devops, chocolatey

I am running selenium tests on Azure DevOps via the release pipelines. I am trying to specify the version of the Google Chrome i wish to use on the GUI, but when i declare it it fails straight away, but the Chocolatey website approves of the version. I am thinking maybe the syntax in which i am declaring the Google Chrome version is incorrect?

[image: Azure DevOps Release Piepline Chochlatey Configuration]

I also declared the version below, where it says "The version of the package that is to be installed", but it fails also.

Another question; is there a way to declare the width of Google Chrome for these tests when they are being ran via Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

The [Chocolatey package website](https://chocolatey.org/packages/GoogleChrome/86.0.4240.75) states that CLI command to install that specific version of Google Chrome is:

```
choco install googlechrome --version=86.0.4240.75
```

So my guess is that you should set `googlechrome` as the package id ("The id of the package(s) that are to be installed"), and `86.0.4240.75` for the version field.

Comment: I tried this already, but sadly the issue was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Adil Leghari's comment within [Chocolatey GoogleChrome 86.0.4240.75 package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/GoogleChrome/86.0.4240.75) page:

> Just a heads up, there is a version mis-match on this package, and it may partly be the fault of Google. The Google Chrome Enterprise site lists the version as 86.0.4240.75, but the actual MSI package is stating a version of 68.36.75. This may be a problem for folks who are attempting to track and audit package versions.

Hence you must be facing the issue.

---

### Solution

The latest published GoogleChrome version is **86.0.4240.193**.

[image: 86.0.4240.193]

So as a solution you can either:

- Specify *The id of the package(s) that are to be installed* as: **GoogleChrome 86.0.4240.183**
- Else run the following command from the command line or from PowerShell:

  ```
  choco install googlechrome --version=86.0.4240.193
  ```